# console.log, where did my typescript line numbers go?

Tags: angular, typescript

My break points don't bind in VSCode and on top of that, I'm not getting typescript line numbers in the console.  I think they are related. sourceMaps=true in tsconfig.json.

How do I get line numbers back in the console in my angular app?

[image]

Comment: What command did you use to run your app?

Comment: Hello, what is the Angular version of your project?

Comment: Screenshots of IDEs are unfortunately not appropriate here. [Please replace images of code/logs/errors/tooltips with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: it's ng serve.  it's in chrome, developer tools, console

Comment: it's 16.0.1 angular version

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your issue is related to configuration.

Here are the logs from my machine using a new Angular project.

Logs after running `ng serve -c production`:

```
main-MVCVS4N4.js:1 Test logging
polyfills-LZBJRJJE.js:1 Angular is running in development mode.
```

Logs after running `ng serve` (which defaults to `development` configuration):

```
app.component.ts:16 Test logging
core.mjs:29995 Angular is running in development mode.
```

If needed, you can create new Angular projects to see what your logs look like and also check your `angular.json` configuration.

---

**UPDATE**
You should also make sure that source maps are enabled in Chrome.
With Chrome DevTools open and in focus, press `F1` to open the settings page.
Under `Preferences` tab, check the `Enable JavaScript source maps` option. Alternatively, you can click on `Restore defaults and reload` button (same tab in the lower right corner).

I made a new test with your exact version (`16.0.1`) and I got the same results. You should be able to see the log `Angular is running in development mode`.

If it still does not work, consider sharing the logs from `ng version`, your Chrome version and also the exact steps you took to create and serve a new Angular app.

If you use the Angular CLI, it should be as simple as this:

```bash
ng new app --defaults
cd app
ng serve -o
```

Comment: I don't get either of those log messages, coming out of polyfills or core.mjs.  I did log the `.production` flag from the environment and that is properly false.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Tell me if it is helpful.

Comment: John - Other projects I have work just fine. I also did a ng new and that worked fine.  It's something about "this" project and I think it ultimately is something of an ng upgrade problem (multiple times over multiple years).  I've started to upgrade to angular 17 but that has turned out to be difficult.

Comment: One last advice I can give you is to reset your project's repository. You can run `npm ci && ng cache clean`. If it does not work, I would look into `angular.json`. Good luck!